# How to update database connection in Rstudio global environment via shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, odbc

I have the `shiny` app below in which when I give the password and press the actionbutton I want to see that the connection is established in my Rstudio global environment like when I attempt it manually, outside of the shiny app environment (in the upper right corner box that includes all global environment ojects in Rstudio). I have created an `app` file and a `global` file for this reason. When I do this I have to use that `con` connection in order to process the data and also update all the objects I create based on this connection.

**app.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px"
)


shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px"
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      passwordInput("pwd",label = "",value = "",width = "100%" ),
      actionButton('button', "Continue"),
    )
    
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
  }
  )
)
```

**global.r**

```
library(odbc) 
con<- dbConnect(odbc(),
                driver   = "SQL Server",
                database = "databasename",
                server   = svr,
                port     = 1433,
                UID      = "uid",
                PWD      = input$pwd)
practicename<-dbGetQuery(con,"select practicename from practice")[1,1]
year<-75
sqlo<- "select count(extractionoptout)
from patients where extractionoptout=1
and getdate()>dateadd(year,75,dob)"


tm<-data.table(dbGetQuery(con,sqlm))
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to use this connection in your app or in RStudio. Also will this app run only on desktop computer with a single user or more widely on a server (in this case it's not a good idea to put this in global)

Comment: The app will be used to to pass the password to connect to the database. The data are ploted normally in rmd file when I do not use the shiny app and work directly from RStudio, but when I try to give the password via shiny app it does not work. So Im trying to update my global environment via shiny and then display results in rmd. And I work on a server. This is related Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617837/achieve-a-database-connection-to-rmd-document-via-shiny-app

Comment: I still don't get it your process ! When launching a Shiny app if there is a global.r file it will be sourced before sourcing ui.r/server.r or app.r and start of Shiny server. global.r is also out of shiny session scope so using input$pwd is not possible there. By environment to you mean R environment or system environment variables (Sys.getenv()) ? How/who will run the rmd ?

Comment: Different users with different passwords. I can create the rmd when I run it in Rstudio and establish the connection but not when I give the password as input via shiny

Comment: Will the rmd run on the server or on user rstudio (by the way is it RStudio server or desktop version). If rmd is to be run on server, provide password as rmd parameter (see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html) as connection is done in your rmd file